# Can I use Java 17 record with Cassandra table?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, record, java-17

[image]

I know that final class cannot be used for Hibernate Entity, but can it be used for cassandra?

```java
@Table("custom_table")
public record MyTable(
  @PrimaryKey @Column("id") String id, 
  @Column("options") Options options) {

}
```